# No module named 'gensim.sklearn_api'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gensim

I try to use

```
from gensim.sklearn_api import W2VTransformer
```

and get

```
ImportError: No module named 'gensim.sklearn_api'
```

I used

```
import gensim
import sklearn
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
```

and get the same.
In [sklearn_api.w2vmodel – Scikit learn wrapper for word2vec model](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/sklearn_api/w2vmodel.html) I could find no advice. 
How to install `gensim.sklearn_api`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tursunWali

Class names seem to have changed from v1.0.5. Try calling TFIDF and other methods by prefixing them with `do_`, e.g. `hero.do_tfidf`.

Here's a minimal example:

`df['pca']=(df['text'].pipe(hero.clean).pipe(hero.do_tfidf).pipe(hero.do_pca))`

You can see all the class names in the package source code.

Comment: Thank you! Got it working with the `do_tfidf` and going back to 1.0.5 with pip install texthero==1.0.5

Answer (score 1):

If you're using vanilla Python, [`pip install -U gensim`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/install.html).

Answer (score 1):

After importing the "texthero" library. Its shown error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim.sklearn_api'

I have tried to install 'gensim.sklearn_api', but no such module available yet.

Also created the new anaconda environment for an older version of python-like 3.6 and 3.7 but it's has shown the same error message.

Finally, I have installed the older version of texthero and its work

> pip install texthero==1.0.5

The older version of texthero==1.0.5 is very much compatible with python version like 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8
[image]

Comment: I did install textHero 1.0.5, it passes above error, but shows new error: textHere has no attribute TFIDF. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the version, try: `pip install "gensim==3.8.3"`.