# I am getting the following error when importing import texthero as hero

Tags: python, word-embedding

I have been trying to load texthero into python but keep getting this error. I have already upgraded the gensim module.

Error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-0692be95f55a> in <module>()
----> 1 import texthero as hero
      2 import pandas as pd

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/texthero/preprocessing.py in <module>()
     22 warnings.filterwarnings(action="ignore", category=UserWarning, module="gensim")
     23 
---> 24 from gensim.sklearn_api.phrases import PhrasesTransformer
     25 
     26 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim.sklearn_api'
```

Comment: for some bizzare reason it seems to be working fine on Jupyter but not on google colab!

Comment: A quick google search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51429975/no-module-named-gensim-sklearn-api

Comment: yes I have already done the search before posting and the recommendation does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a potential conflict with a newer version of `gensim`, in my case 4.0.1.

`pip install "gensim==3.8.1"`

solved this for me.

Comment: yes this worked for me too. I will try and report so they can address this bug. You're a star!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip install -U gensim
```

And

```
pip install texthero
```

Comment: Try and let see the other answer posted by @Frodnar

Answer (score 0):

There's some issue with newer version. Try installing older version.
pip install texthero==1.0.5 --> it'll do the magic

Answer (score 0):

The following two commands worked for me:

```
pip install "gensim==4.2.0"
pip install "texthero==1.0.5"
```

looks like that package pair is compatible.